# Spark SQL Query Planning Performance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Aim**: Execute a simple `select count(*) from hive_table where partition_col = x` using pyspark sql.

The partition being queried is ~1.2 TB with ~250 000 parquet files.

**Issue**: Upon job submission, spark context is created and job only starts executing after 3 hours. No sign of job submission in Spark UI until execution begins. Actual job completed in ~9mins as per the spark UI.

My assumption is that the sql catalyst reading metadata and planning the sql query could be contributing to the delay.

Any solutions or methods to debugging the above ?

Currently using `Spark 2.4.0`.

Comment: i think the problem comes from the huge number of files you have. You shoud try to reduce the number and see if it changes something.

Comment: What is your cluster configuration? You can take the output of the pyspark sql in a dataframe variable and run `explain` on it to see the execution plan and also see what are the number of partitions that dataframe has.

Comment: Cluster Config: 100 executors, executor memory: 20G , executor cores: 10, driver memory: 30G .  Explain plan takes just as long to return.   Will attempt to grab the output and paste here